# Subtract Value at Aggregate by Quarter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Values are for two groups by quarter.

In DAX, need to summarize all the data but also need to remove -3 from each quarter in 2021 for Group 1, without allowing the value to go below 0.

**This only impacts:**

- Group 1 Only
- 2021 Only

However, **I also need to retain the data details without the adjustment.** So I can't do this in Power Query. My data detail is actually in months but I'm only listing one date per quarter for brevity.

**Data:**

| Group | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2020 | 10 |
| 1 | 04/01/2020 | 8 |
| 1 | 07/01/2020 | 18 |
| 1 | 10/01/2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 07/01/2021 | 7 |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 01/01/2020 | 10 |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 8 |
| 2 | 07/01/2020 | 18 |
| 2 | 10/01/2020 | 2 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 12 |
| 2 | 04/01/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 07/01/2021 | 7 |
| 2 | 10/01/2021 | 2 |

**Result:**

| Group | Qtr/Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1-2020 | 10 |
| 1 | Q2-2020 | 8 |
| 1 | Q3-2020 | 18 |
| 1 | Q4-2020 | 2 |
| 1 | **2020** | 38 |
| 1 | Q1-2021 | **9** |
| 1 | Q2-2021 | **0** |
| 1 | Q3-2021 | **4** |
| 1 | Q4-2021 | **0** |
| 1 | **2021** | **13** |
| 2 | Q1-2020 | 10 |
| 2 | Q2-2020 | 8 |
| 2 | Q3-2020 | 18 |
| 2 | Q4-2020 | 2 |
| 2 | **2020** | 2 |
| 2 | Q1-2021 | 12 |
| 2 | Q2-2021 | 3 |
| 2 | Q3-2021 | 7 |
| 2 | Q4-2021 | 2 |
| 2 | **2021** | 24 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue can be solved by using `Matrix Table`, and also to `add new column` to process value before create the table:

**First, add a new column using following formula:**

```
Revised value = 
var newValue = IF(YEAR(Sheet1[Date])=2021,Sheet1[Value]-3,Sheet1[Value])
return
IF(newValue <0,0,newValue)
```

[image]

**Second, create the matrix table for the desired outcome:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! An additional question, how could I get it to only impact the year aggregate? So -12 for the full year?

Comment: I think it is unlikely to minus on the total only, but to adjust each `Date` value,  unless you try to create each measure for `each Quarter, Year` so on, but it is unpractical method